# Is there an equivalent of Bottle or Sinatra for Perl6 or Perl5?

Tags: perl, raku

I'm making a decision today about something.  Is there a simple web framework like python's Bottle, or Ruby's Sinatra, for perl5 | perl6 ?

If so, where would I find it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) comes very close and aims to be Sinatra for Perl.

[Mojolicious::Lite](http://www.mojolicious.org/) is another very simple approach on web development.

Answer (score 7):

For Perl 5 there exists a lot of Frameworks:

- [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/)
- [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)
- [Mojolicious](http://www.mojolicious.org/)
- [Jifty](http://jifty.org/view/HomePage)

There are a lot more. What you also want to look at is at [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/). [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) is a general interface for communication between web servers and perl web frameworks. [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) is an implementation of it. One of the most used Framework at the moment is probably [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/). On the [Plack](http://plackperl.org/) page you found a lot more web frameworks.

Comment: I knew there were lots of frameworks for Perl. I was looking for frameworks for perl _like Bottle or Sinatra_, which does not include Catalyst, or Jifty

Comment: I think Catalyst fits in there very well. Yes, Jifty probably not. I have given you a complete list, where you can see what fits best for you.

Answer (score 2):

[Bailador](https://modules.perl6.org/search/?q=bailador) and [Cro](http://cro.services/) are two quite advanced microservices frameworks in Perl 6.